# Find file type reverse

Tags: find

On my image folder i want only images,so i will find all video files "intruders" using this command(found somewhere on stackexchange)

```
find folder/imageonly  -type f -exec file -N -i -- {} + |sed -n 's!: video/[^:]*$!!p'
```

But if i want a reverse search?
For example i want to find all not video files in video folder?

p.s=i don't use extensions,so flags "file -N -i.." must be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an address range to your `sed`:

```
find folder/imageonly  -type f -exec file -N -i -- {} + |
  sed -n '/: video\/[^:]*$/!s!: [[:alnum:]]*/[^:]*$!!p'
```

`/: video\/[^:]*$/!` tells it to run the commands on every line that doesn't match the pattern, which you used for matching videos.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just use grep instead of sed (mainly because i have no experience with sed). But the following should work (and does on my system):

```
find .  -type f -exec file -N -i -- {} + | grep -v 'video/' | cut -d : -f 1
```

This expects that there are no *:* in the filenames though.